# Update existing table if first and second column matched and append if new data is present

Tags: python, google-sheets, streamlit

I am trying to update my code, but I am having a hard time how to properly do it since I am still new in this python coding stuff.

the python app basically is where you will upload 3 separate xlsx files and the app will process, clean, and transfer the data to the target google sheet file that has 3 separate tab for each xlsx files. Now I want to do something like, if the first and second column is matched with the target sheet in its specific tab, it will update that row/s, and if the xlsx files contains something that is not present in the google sheet file, it should add it.

here is the code block:

```
    # Function to clean and transform Sales data
    def clean_and_transform_sales_data(df):
        # Group by Createdate and Prod_Category, and sum the relevant columns
        sales_cleaned = df.groupby(['Createdate', 'Prod_Category'])[['Qty Ordered', 'Revenue - LineTotal', 'Gross Profit Cash']].sum().reset_index()
        sales_cleaned['Createdate'] = sales_cleaned['Createdate'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        return sales_cleaned

    # Function to clean and transform Production data
    def clean_and_transform_production_data(df):
        # Group by CreatedON and Prod_Category, and sum the QtyTotal column
        production_cleaned = df.groupby(['CreatedON', 'Prod_Category'])['QtyTotal'].sum().reset_index()
        production_cleaned['CreatedON'] = production_cleaned['CreatedON'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        return production_cleaned

    # Function to clean and transform Purchasing data
    def clean_and_transform_purchasing_data(df):
        # Group by CreatedON and Prod_Category, and sum the QtyOrdered column
        purchasing_cleaned = df.groupby(['CreatedON', 'Prod_Category'])['QtyOrdered'].sum().reset_index()
        purchasing_cleaned['CreatedON'] = purchasing_cleaned['CreatedON'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        return purchasing_cleaned

    # Function to upload data to Google Sheets
    def upload_data_to_google_sheets(data, worksheet):
        # Append the data to the worksheet
        worksheet.append_rows(data.values.tolist(), value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')

    # Function to upload and process files
    def process_files():
        sales_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Sales File (xlsx)", type=["xlsx"])
        production_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Production File (xlsx)", type=["xlsx"])
        purchasing_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Purchasing File (xlsx)", type=["xlsx"])

        upload_button = st.button("Upload")

        if upload_button:
            with st.spinner("Uploading and processing data..."):
                if sales_file and production_file and purchasing_file:
                    try:
                        sales_df = pd.read_excel(sales_file)
                        production_df = pd.read_excel(production_file)
                        purchasing_df = pd.read_excel(purchasing_file)

                        # Clean and transform data for each dataset
                        sales_cleaned = clean_and_transform_sales_data(sales_df)
                        production_cleaned = clean_and_transform_production_data(production_df)
                        purchasing_cleaned = clean_and_transform_purchasing_data(purchasing_df)

                        # Upload cleaned data to Google Sheets
                        sales_worksheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key).worksheet("DB_Sales")
                        upload_data_to_google_sheets(sales_cleaned, sales_worksheet)

                        production_worksheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key).worksheet("DB_Production")
                        upload_data_to_google_sheets(production_cleaned, production_worksheet)

                        purchasing_worksheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key).worksheet("DB_Purchasing")
                        upload_data_to_google_sheets(purchasing_cleaned, purchasing_worksheet)

                        st.success("Data uploaded successfully!")
                    except Exception as e:
                        st.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called UPSERT (update or insert) and is supported in some databases. The way to implement this is to first check if the data you're trying to insert exists in the table (think of an excel sheet as a DB table). It depends on the file itself, is it indexed/sorted in any way? if yes then it's easy to do this using either index lookup or binary search. If not then you need to go through the dataset you already have (google sheet) and create a dictionary where the keys are (col1_value,col2_value) and the vales are the row numbers.

For example, if you have the following table:

```
name    | city    | age
_________________________
John    | London  | 20
_________________________
Mark    | New York| 30
```

your dictionary will be: `{('John', 'London') : 0, ('Mark','New York') : 1}`

This will be your index metadata.
Then you go through the 3 files that you want to process and for each file, you check the name and city against your index and if it exits there, you get which row that data is at and update the values in that row. If it doesn't exist there, you add it both to your index (dictionary) AND to the google sheet.

For example, let's imagine this is the data from one of your Excel sheets:

```
name    | city    | age
_________________________
John    | London  | 21
_________________________
Jack    | Rome    | 25
```

we know that `('John', 'London')` is in your index, so we get its row number (which is 0) and update the age column at row 0. Then we check `('Jack', 'Rome')` which is not in your index, so you write it to your Google sheet (let's say you previously had 10 rows) at row 11 and add it to your index `index[('Jack', 'Rome')]=10 #11th row has an index of 10` so your index is looking like:

```
 {('John', 'London') : 0,
  ('Mark','New York') : 1,
  ('Jack', 'Rome') : 10}
```

to be honest, I haven't used Google Sheets via Python, so I can't give you an exact code but I hope the concept is easy to understand. It shouldn't be more than 10 lines of code to create, check, and update your index.

Edit:
here is a code example just using the data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

google_sheet = pd.DataFrame([('John', 'London', 20), ('Mark','New York', 30)],columns =['Name', 'City', 'Age'])
excel_sheet = pd.DataFrame([('John', 'London', 21), ('Jack', 'Rome', 25)],columns =['Name', 'City', 'Age'])

index = {(row['Name'],row['City']) : i for i, row in google_sheet.iterrows()}
print('Before: ')
print(google_sheet)
print(index)
print("#"*100)

for _, row in excel_sheet.iterrows():
    key = (row['Name'],row['City']) 
    if key in index:
        row_number = index[key]
        google_sheet.at[row_number,'Age'] = row['Age']
    else:
        index[key] = len(google_sheet)
        google_sheet.loc[len(google_sheet)] = row

print('After: ')
print(google_sheet)
print(index)
print("#"*100)
```

You just need to call the correct APIs to read from / read to the Google sheet.

Edit2: If this is a common operation or your workplace is using CSVs/Excel/Google sheet as a DB (you'd be surprised how common that is, despite DBs like mySQL being free ...), I highly recommend you store the index as a file somewhere or if possible sort by the columns that will be used for UPSERT, otherwise the performance will be horrible. Also, try to do as much of the data manipulation as possible in memory and send results to the API in batches to avoid repeated slow network calls.